# paste and resize excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to paste an image into a powerpoint slide, and then resize it once I have it pasted,

I dont know the image idex so it needs to be able to be resized immediately afterr being pasted

below doesnt work, please can someone help

```
Sub PasteOnSlide()

Dim strPresPath As String
strPresPath = "c://myfile"
Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)

oPPTFile.Slides(4).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).select

With Selection
    .Height = 270
    .Width = 680
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 120
    .ZOrder msoSendToBack
End With

End Sub
```

i also tried:

```
set MyShape = oPPTFile.Slides(4).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).select
With MyShape
    .Height = 270
    .Width = 680
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 120
    .ZOrder msoSendToBack
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You already activated the Microsoft PowerPoint XX.X Object Library? If so, what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Oh so close...

Avoid useing `Select`, (and declare all your variables!)

```
Sub PasteOnSlide()
    Dim strPresPath As String
    Dim MyShape As Shape
    Dim oPPTFile As Presentation
    Dim oPPTApp As Application

    Set oPPTApp = Application
    strPresPath = "c://myfile"
    Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)

    Set MyShape = oPPTFile.Slides(4).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Item(1)

    With MyShape
        .Height = 270
        .Width = 680
        .Left = 20
        .Top = 120
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With
End Sub
```

You should add error handling, including to cover the case where there is nothing in the clipboard to paste, or where `strPresPath` does not point to an existing presentation file.